# Add startup options to a file (Windows)

Tags: windows, command, hex, editor

Is it possible to add startup options directly to the exe instead of a link file?
F. e. You have the command "-minimized". Now you can just add this to the shortcut file and the program will start minimized. 
Is there a way to do this to the exe file directly? (Hex Editor?)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In order to physically change an executable file it would need to be modified from source code and recompiled. I don't recommend changing anything in an executable file using a Hex Editor unless you are an expert and know what you are doing to reverse engineer an application.

I would suggest that you simply create a shortcut and modify that to minimize / maximize the application on open as you mentioned. That way you won't risk completely corrupting the executable.